# How to customize getter & setter in Realm Swift?

Tags: realm, realm-cocoa

I'm new to Realm, I used to use MagicalRecord before.

In MagicalRecord, I can handle import function or even set some mappingKeys for multiple candidate names.

I would like to customize some of the properties of my Realm object.

I found `DynamicObject` that looks like what I want. However, I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

To customize your getters and setters with Realm Swift, you will need to define a plain underlying stored property. You can then access this property from another you define on top of that with custom setters and getters as seen below.

```
public class Foo : Object {
    private dynamic var _bar: Int

    public var bar: Int {
        get {
            return _bar + 1
        }
        set {
            _bar = newValue - 1
        }
    }
}
```

Note that using Swift's `willSet` or `didSet` with Realm Swift might not work like you expect. They are only triggered for unattached standalone objects. Once you persist an object or retrieve a persisted obejct, all getters and setters are overridden to directly access the persisted values.

---

`DynamicObject` is not what you want to use. This is intended for use-cases, where you don't have strong guarantees over your object schema and need to deal with either unstructured data or databases you didn't created yourself.